# why localhost:3000/?age=12 works but localhost:3000/?age="12" doesn't in Express Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

When working on middleware's in Node JS, i have implemented a code on if age>=18 user can access the website otherwise not but when i type query like  localhost:3000/?age=12 it works but localhost:3000/?age="12" it doesn't works  anyone knew why it  happens and how to resolve it

code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// middleware
// req,res we need to modify so it is there
// next is a function it will proceed when route is called
    const reqFilter=(req,res,next)=>{
        console.log('reqFilter');
    // we have to call next otherwise it will keep loading in browaer
    // eg:-> if age is older then 18 user can access page
    
    
        if(req.query.age<18){
            res.send('Please Confirm You are over 18')
        }
        else if(!req.query.age){
            res.send("please put down age")
        }
        else{
            next();
        }
    
        
    
    
}




  // using the middleware
app.use(reqFilter)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("welcome to homepage")
})

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    res.send("welcome to users page")
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 2):

From express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html.

```
As req.query’s shape is based on user-controlled input, all properties and values in this object are untrusted and should be validated before trusting. For example, req.query.foo.toString() may fail in multiple ways, for example, foo may not be there or may not be a string, and toString may not be a function and instead of a string or other user-input.
```

You're comparing the query parameter to the **Number 18**, You need to check the type of the query. You can do so with `if (typeof req.query.age == 'string')` and perhaps convert the "18" to a Number.
You can do so by adding `+` like that: `+req.query.age`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, manually type checking leaves a lot of loopholes in making of production level website is there any alternative that can type check each query entered?